# Is a comma required in "Until now X, that it is about time we do Y"?

Tags: punctuation, commas

I am wondering if I should leave the comma in the following sentence:

> Until now he has been behaving so badly, that it is about time we do
>   something about it.

Comment: I would probably write it as "It is time we do something about his bad behavior".

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603360/2085).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use a comma in that sentence. Most of the confusion with *that* comes with defining and none defining relative clauses.

We went to the restaurant that serves the best nachos ever. Here *that* is used to introduce a relative cause and could be replaced with *which*. The clause defines the restaurant that they went to. In modern English *that* is frequently used instead of *which*.

She wore a black mini skirt, that looked totally stupid on her.

Here *that* introduces a non-defining relative clause, and I would be inclined to use a comma, though Microsoft Word would have an issue with this. Again *that* replaces *which* to introduce the non-defining relative clause, but *that* sounds more natural.

Comment: Er, are you sure that's a relative clause in the OP's example?

Answer (score 1):

As you've written it, it doesn't need a comma. But if I was writing it, I'd change the wording a little:

**Up to** now he has been behaving so badly that it's about time we **did** something about it.

That's not to say that there's anything ungrammatical about "until now", but "up to now" is more colloquial. It might be even more colloquial to shift it to the end of the first clause, and say "He's been behaving so badly up to now..."

Answer (score 1):

> *"Until now he has been behaving so badly, that it is about time we do something about it."*

The expression "that it is about time we do something about it" is a content clause, which is licensed by the modifier "so" and is an indirect complement in the adverb phrase headed by "badly".

Usually there is no comma inserted between a head and its complement.